# AngularJS : How to call methods from "Different Controllers" via single <ul> element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a team working together. And then the main `app.js` (like below) is given by another team. (Meaning: I don't have control on it. So i can't change it's existing structure.) The App is something like:

```
app
.value('settings', {
    hostUrl: "//example.com",
    endpoint:'/api/events/',
})
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.initUser = function(e){
        console.log("User stuffs..");
    }
}])
.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.initEvent = function(e){
        console.log("Event stuffs..");
    }
}])
```

( This is not the real one, but just a sample skeleton)

Here's my part below. I NEED TO call two methods (in two controllers) above within a single `<ul><li>` element, respectively:

```
<ul>
    <li>User</li>
    <li>Event</li>
</ul>
```

But:
What i understand (what i can do) so far is, something like:

```
<ul ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <li ng-click="initUser();">User</li>
</ul>
<ul ng-controller="EventCtrl">
    <li ng-click="initEvent();">Event</li>
</ul>
```

How can i make this calls in single `<ul> list` please? Like in:

```
<ul>
    <li>User</li>
    <li>Event</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks everyone for helping out :)

Comment: manage it as services, so in your controller you can inject the other team service and use their functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-click="initUser();">User</li>
    <li ng-controller="EventCtrl" ng-click="initEvent();">Event</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's simply what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Any data or functionality that needs to work across controller boundaries should be implemented as a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).